# Toggle text on checkbox state change

Tags: jquery, toggle

I'm not trying to do anything fancy... just want the content of the "noshowuntilchangevelocity" class to toggle between shown and hidden when it's specific checkbox state changes.

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {

     $("input#velocity").change(function()
        {
            $('#noshowuntilchangevelocity').toggle();
        });

 });
<input id="velocity" name="velocity" type="checkbox"value="Y" checked>
<div id="noshowuntilchangevelocity"style="display: hidden;">
<p class="bolder">You are changing this selection</p>
</div>
```

Comment: add JsFiddle link and ask the question

Comment: Which version of jQuery?

Comment: It is working for me as it is http://jsfiddle.net/ZJmw3/

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two small errors:

- You need to add a space between `id="noshowuntilchangevelocity"` and `style="display:none;"`
- You need to use `display:none;` and not `display:hidden;`

Here is a correct version:

```
<input id="velocity" name="velocity" type="checkbox" value="Y" checked>
<div id="noshowuntilchangevelocity" style="display: none;">
    <p class="bolder">You are changing this selection</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
    $('#noshowuntilchangevelocity').hide()
     $("input#velocity").change(function()
        {
            $('#noshowuntilchangevelocity').toggle();
        });

 });
<input id="velocity" name="velocity" type="checkbox" value="Y" checked>
<div id="noshowuntilchangevelocity">
    <p class="bolder">You are changing this selection</p>
</div>
```

Or Steve's solution works fine too.

Comment: That is literally exactly what I had a few minutes ago -- still not working.  The site has twig and bootstrap - and there are some conditionals in there -- something must not be closed properly since it's still not working.

Comment: If you have it open in Chrome, inspect element and check your console. You may have a global JS exception that is preventing this from running.

Answer (score 0):

I figured I'd pop back and explain the problem since everyone's answers and my original code both worked fine.  Turns out I'd included the bootstrap files two times - once in the modal, and once on the original page.  Once I'd pulled that out it went back to behaving :)

Thanks for the help though all.